# Laravel Auth error with session

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working on an old database which I can not modify.

What I'm trying to do is a Login for users for that database, the **username** and **password** fields are with another name so I had to change some variables in Laravel and it is working, it redirects me to **/home** if the authentication is valid.

The problem is that when the redirection is done, the session files are created but the session is **NULL** so the user is redirected to **login** page again.

I have seen a lot of threads with this similar issue, but no answer has worked for me.

## model http://pastebin.com/TZviQwDA

## controller http://pastebin.com/nQ5KSGmU

Comment: My understanding of your post is that you can't update the database but instead have full access to code. Is that so? Please confirm.

Comment: Can you edit the question and post your controller and your user model ?

Comment: @menjaraz yes, I'm creating an administrator with an existing database

Comment: 1) Is "an existing" a replication of the "old database, you can not modify" or the same?

Comment: 2) Not quite sure of what you mean by "session files": `Session Cookie`or actually the `Session File` created by the framework?

Comment: @menjaraz `Session File` created by the framework at `app/storage`, and it is the same database.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother messing up with Variables and so on!

Assuming knowing the user's `id` (no need to know neither *username* nor *password*), you can emulate programmatically a login using the following snippet where id=1 or pick up another valid one:

```
$user = User::find(1);

Auth::login($user);
```

or even better:

```
Auth::loginUsingId(1);
```

Comment: It works, but also it works with the Auth::attempt when its **in** the  login controller, once its redirected, its not longer logged in

Answer (score 0):

I "fixed" my problem by downgrading Laravel to 4.0, I suppose I will wait until a new version to see if it works.

Thanks.

Comment: Laravel v4.1.29 was released 4 hours ago!